# play framework in heroku with maven

Tags: maven, heroku, playframework

I have a play framework (v1.2.4) app deployed in heroku. Then I added maven module on my play app.

```
module.maven=${play.path}/modules/maven-head
```

so every time I update (play maven:up), I get the latest jar(s) from local repository.

I tested it locally and they work no problem. Now major problems when I deploy to Heroku.

I can see heroku slug complier thinks this is a maven app and not a play app. But this isn't correct. This is not a maven app, its a play app. Only reason pom is there so that I can get updates of my other core project.

I want to be able to tell Heroku that this is a play app and not maven. Just treat it as play app and deploy.

Can someone please help me ..

Many thanks 
Kind regards 
--Rana Das

Answer (score 0):

When you create the app specify the Play buildpack:

```
heroku create -s cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play.git
```

Comment: Thanks James, that worked. But I'm surprised why heroku slug compiler  starts a maven build of my app (the moment push is finished) even though there is no pom file.

Comment: That is odd.  You might want to submit a support request.

Comment: I did (ticket #47038) and I was suggested to add : 

heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play.git

Pretty much same what you said. Like I said, its working now. But why must I add a config when there is nothing maven related except in git history. 

Thank for your help.
--Rana

Comment: Not really sure.  The first time you push to Heroku the buildpack is determined based on the files that are present.  Then the same buildpack is used until changed.