# Heroku Push rejected - no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: java, git, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I made a new project with Play Framework I can't seem to push it to Heroku. I used the below code to create the heroku app since I was using Maven too.

```
heroku create -s cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play.git
```

[from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840439/play-framework-in-heroku-with-maven). AFAIK I have all the files I need. I have application.conf in conf/

```
Counting objects: 35, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 94.25 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 35 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:peaceful-depths-9995.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:peaceful-depths-9995.git'
```

Files being committed:

```
[master (root-commit) d975f1a] Init
 21 files changed, 8682 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 Procfile
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/Application.java
 create mode 100644 app/views/index.scala.html
 create mode 100644 app/views/main.scala.html
 create mode 100644 conf/application.conf
 create mode 100644 conf/routes
 create mode 100644 pom.xml
 create mode 100644 project/Build.scala
 create mode 100644 project/build.properties
 create mode 100644 project/plugins.sbt
 create mode 100644 public/css/bootstrap.css
 create mode 100644 public/css/bootstrap.min.css
 create mode 100644 public/images/favicon.png
 create mode 100644 public/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js
 create mode 100644 public/js/bootstrap.js
 create mode 100644 public/js/bootstrap.min.js
 create mode 100644 public/stylesheets/main.css
 create mode 100644 test/ApplicationTest.java
 create mode 100644 test/IntegrationTest.java
```

Any reason why it being let through? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the Play 1 Heroku buildpack.  Play Framework 2+ apps require the `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git` buildpack.